# PHP read value form multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

its easy for sure..
i have code like this:

```
$indeks = 0;
foreach ($list as $k => $v)
{

    $data['fname'] = $customer->firstname;
    $data['lname'] = $customer->lastname;
    $data['code'] = $code['code'];

    $tablica[$indeks] = $data;
    $indeks++;
```

and i want to read only 'code' value for each array.

i try:

```
foreach($tablica as $k => $v){
    foreach ($v as $key => $value ) {
        echo $value
    }
}
```

but i get all arrays values.

when i try

```
foreach($tablica as $k => $v){
    foreach ($v['code'] as $key => $value ) {
        echo $value
    }
}
```

i have nothing...

thx for help

Comment: the loop at the top makes no sense. You're not using `$k` or `$v` anywhere in the loop. What is `$customer` and `$code`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-column.php) function to get all values of column, for example:

```
foreach (array_column($tablica, 'code') as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a For loop should help

```
for($i=0;$i<count($tablica);$i++){
    echo $tablica[$i]['code'];
}
```

or get all Codes into an Array

```
    $code = array();

    for($i=0;$i<count($tablica);$i++){
        $code[$i] = $tablica[$i]['code'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need nested loops.

```
foreach ($tablica as $value) {
    echo $value['code'];
}
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/8WWFNo)

Comment: return nothing - empty

Comment: Then there's something wrong with how you filled in `$tablica`. I've added a demo showing that it works.